# Safari break on attribute change

Tags: safari, webkit, safari-web-inspector

In chrome there is the ability to break on DOM modification or attribute change.

Is there any such functionality in Safari? Or something similar.

Comment: I'm also looking for this and can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that as of Safari v9.0.3, the ability to break on DOM modifications does not exist in the Safari Developer Tools.